# Can somebody tell me why this Jquery tooltip is not showing up?

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery-tooltip/jquery.tooltip.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-tooltip/jquery.tooltip.js"></script>


<div id="baby" title="My tootip">The text</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('#baby').tooltip({
    track: true,
    delay: 0,
    showURL: false,
    showBody: " - ",
    extraClass: "pretty",
    fixPNG: true,
    opacity: 0.95,
    left: -120
});
});
</script>
```

The files are found, and they are not 404.

Comment: Have you also loaded jQuery itself?  It is not included in your source.

Answer (score 0):

Can't confirm your problem. Your code copy/pasted works just fine

Demo http://jsbin.com/iwojo3